# Error in "names": incorrect number of layer names

Tags: r

I have in my script the following instructions:

```
library(raster)
wc25 <- stack(list.files(path="./Rhaebo/Bio_PresWC1.4/", pattern = "\\.asc$", full.names = TRUE))
names(wc25) <- c("bio1","bio4", "bio8", "bio9","bio10", "bio11", "bio12", "bio13", "bio14", "bio15", "bio16", "bio17", "bio18", "bio19")
```

but when I run it, it throws me the following message:

```
Error in `names<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("bio1", "bio4", "bio8", "bio9",  : 
  incorrect number of layer names
```

Does anyone know what could cause this problem?

Comment: What do you get when you type `length(names(wc25))` into the console? It seems likely that this will be different from the vector of names you are passing.

Comment: I get 19 when I type length(names(wc25)), I realize that I'm only putting 14 name vectors, I'll try putting all 19!